# Unable to Connect to any MQTT Broker from my Local machine using HiveMQ Async Clienr

Tags: scala, mqtt, mosquitto, hivemq

I have the following publish method that connects to a given broker and sends a message and then disconnects:

```
 def publish(mqttCfg: MqttConfig, topic: String, mqttQos: MqttQos): Future[Unit] = {
    val client = asyncMqttClient(mqttCfg)

    // Define a custom wrapper type to represent the result of the publish operation
    sealed trait PublishResult
    case class SuccessfulPublish(mqttPublishResult: Mqtt5PublishResult) extends PublishResult
    case class FailedPublish(error: Throwable) extends PublishResult

    asyncMqttClient(mqttCfg).connect()
      .thenCompose(_ => client.publishWith().topic(topic).qos(mqttQos).payload("HELLO WORLD!".getBytes()).send())
      .thenAccept(result => {
        val publishResult = Try(result)
        publishResult match {
          case Success(message) =>
            println(s"publishedResult: $message") // TODO: Change to logger
          case Failure(error) =>
            println(s"Failed to publish: ${error.getMessage}") // TODO: Change to logg
        }
      })
      .thenCompose(_ => client.disconnect())
      .thenAccept(_ => println("disconnected"))
      .asScala.map(_ => ())
  }
```

I then have a Scala test that simply tests this like this:

```
  "MqttClientFactory#publish" should "connect to a local MQTT broker and publish" in {
    val mqttConfig = MqttConfig("cpo-platform-test", "test.mosquitto.org", 1883)
    val published = MqttClientFactory.publish(
      mqttConfig,
      "cpo-test-topic",
      MqttQos.EXACTLY_ONCE
    )
    whenReady(published, timeout(Span(100, Seconds))) { Unit => {
      val client = MqttClientFactory.asyncMqttClient(mqttConfig)
      println("In here ****************** ")
      client
        .connect()
        .thenCompose(_ => client.subscribeWith().topicFilter("cpo-test-topic").qos(MqttQos.EXACTLY_ONCE).callback(println).send())
      }
    }
  }
```

When I ran this, it results in the following error on the place where I'm waiting for the Future to complete in the whenReady(......)

```
The future returned an exception of type: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException, with message: com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.MqttClientStateException: MQTT client is not connected..
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.openelectrons.cpo.mqtt.MqttClientFactoryTest at (MqttClientFactoryTest.scala:29)
```

I tried several brokers on my local machine, the eclipse mosquitto broker, the cedalo broker and all of them return the same message. What am I doing wrong? It is so annoying to have a simple connection to get it working. Any help?

EIDT: Further details added:

```
  def asyncMqttClient(mqttCfg: MqttConfig): Mqtt5AsyncClient = {
    Mqtt5Client.builder()
      .identifier(mqttCfg.appName)
      .serverHost(mqttCfg.serverHost)
      .serverPort(mqttCfg.serverPort)
      .simpleAuth()
        .username(mqttCfg.user.getOrElse(""))
        .password(mqttCfg.pass.getOrElse("").getBytes("UTF-8"))
      .applySimpleAuth()
      .buildAsync()
  }
```

I use the following docker compose to start my local mqtt mosquitto server:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mqtt5:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mqtt5
    ports:
      - 1883:1883 #default mqtt port
      - 9001:9001 #default mqtt port for websockets
    volumes:
      - /opt/softwares/mosquitto/mqtt5/config:/mosquitto/config
```

The MQTT broker is successfully started as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

Here is a screenshot of the logs:

[image]

EDIT:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ docker exec -it mqtt5 mosquitto_pub -t /test/message -m 'Hello World!'
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ docker exec -it mqtt5 tail -f /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
1696296934: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696298735: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696300536: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696302337: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696304138: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696305939: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696307740: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data//mosquitto.db.
1696309170: New connection from 127.0.0.1:39422 on port 1883.
1696309170: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:39422 as auto-8817AB58-2BA0-33D2-5AB0-A6176558E97C (p2, c1, k60).
1696309170: Client auto-8817AB58-2BA0-33D2-5AB0-A6176558E97C disconnected.
^Cjoesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ docker exec -it mqtt5 mosquitto_sub -v -t /test/message
/test/message Hello World!
```

With the scala test, I see the following logs:

```
1696310903: New connection from 192.168.208.1:57752 on port 1883.
1696310903: New client connected from 192.168.208.1:57752 as cpo-platform-test (p5, c1, k60).
1696310903: Client cpo-platform-test closed its connection.
```

Comment: I guess the client you are using is [hivemq-mqtt-client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client). That code is not complete. Seems that you are using wrappers. Were you able to connect to the mqtt server using any GUI client such as [mqtt-explorer](http://mqtt-explorer.com/)

Comment: You mean my publish method is not complete?

Comment: I mean, not sure what is inside `MqttClientFactory.asyncMqttClient` (I would guess it returns a `Mqtt5AsyncClient` or similar. The publish method looks pretty similar to the code I posted as an example in the answers. The error message you got is saying that you are not able to connect to the `MQTT client is not connected` and based on the description of the test you have a MQTT server running in your local or test env. Were you able to connect to that server using any client like the one I suggested? Could you give details about how you setup your MQTT server?

Comment: I could not connect to the local mqtt broker using the hive cli as well. It throws Unable to connect. Reason: 'finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused'

Comment: what is inside `/opt/softwares/mosquitto/mqtt5/config` directory? I would guess that you have the file `mosquitto.conf` inside, what is the content of that file? Have you checked the logs of the mosquitto container? Were you able to see if the server started ok or with some issue?

Comment: Yes, inside that folder I have the mosquitto conf that is available here: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/mosquitto.conf

Comment: I just uncommented the listener to add the ports.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: could you show the `log of the mosquitto container` and the content of the of `mosquitto.conf`? have you checked the example of the `docker-compose.yaml` and the `mosquito.conf` I used in the example I posted? When you used the CLI, you got `Connection refused`. Not sure if the auth is not well setup. You could try with no auth required adding the line `allow_anonymous true`

Comment: Will give it a try and post the results later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a simple POC that I was able to run in my local. It doesn't validate anything. I only start a [eclipse-mosquitto](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) container, connect to the service using the [hivemq-mqtt-client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client), publish a message, subscribe to the topic and print the received message to `stdout`.

- `build.sbt`

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.hivemq" % "hivemq-mqtt-client" % "1.3.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % Test,
  "com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-scalatest" % TestcontainersScalaVersion % Test
)
```

- `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.18
    volumes:
      - /absolute/path/to/mosquitto/config/:/mosquitto/config
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:9001
```

- `/absolute/path/to/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

- `DummyMosquittoTest.scala`

```scala
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.scalatest.TestContainersForAll
import com.dimafeng.testcontainers.{DockerComposeContainer, ExposedService}
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.datatypes.MqttQos
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.{Mqtt5AsyncClient, Mqtt5Client}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AsyncFunSuite
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

import java.io.File
import java.util.UUID
import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._

class TestcontainersMainTest
    extends AsyncFunSuite
    with Matchers
    with TestContainersForAll {

  override type Containers = DockerComposeContainer

  override def startContainers(): DockerComposeContainer = {
    DockerComposeContainer
      .Def(
        composeFiles = new File(
          this.getClass.getClassLoader
            .getResource("docker-compose.yaml")
            .getFile
        ),
        exposedServices = Seq(ExposedService(name = "mosquitto", port = 1883))
      )
      .start()
  }

  test("mosquitto container") {
    withContainers { container =>
      val client: Mqtt5AsyncClient = Mqtt5Client
        .builder()
        .identifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .serverHost("broker.hivemq.com")
        .buildAsync()

      client
        .connect()
        .thenCompose(_ =>
          client
            .publishWith()
            .topic("test/topic")
            .payload("some random message!!!".getBytes)
            .send()
        )
        .asScala
        .map(_ => 1 should be(1))

      client
        .subscribeWith()
        .topicFilter("test/topic")
        .qos(MqttQos.EXACTLY_ONCE)
        .callback(x => println(new String(x.getPayloadAsBytes)))
        .send()
        .asScala
        .map(_ => 1 should be(1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it worked. How is this different from the example that I have?

Comment: With the same docker compose file and the same config content, I'm still not able to get my docker set up working.

Comment: Please edit your post sharing the mosquitto.conf and the log messages from the mosquitto container. I don't think the problem is the client.

Comment: I have updated my post with the actual ćonf and the docker compose file.

Comment: Does the docker logs show some message? Maybe check what is inside `/mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log`.

Comment: I use docker compose -f /path/to/docker/compose/file.yaml up -d command to start the eclipse-mosquitto container, but when I remove the up command, it just hangs saying "Attaching to mqtt5"

Comment: without the `-d` flag it happens the same to me. Haven't tried to run the container without that param before. You could try to debug the log of mosquitto defined in your `mosquitto.conf` file. In your case you could run `docker exec -it mqtt5 tail -f /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log`. Also you can use the command to publish a message in a topic and also subscribe to the same topic once the container is started. publish `docker exec -it mqtt5 mosquitto_pub -t /test/message -m 'Hello World!'. subscribe `docker exec -it mqtt5 mosquitto_sub -v -t /test/message`

Comment: I have updated my post with the pub and sub commands and the utput from the log

Comment: have you tried to run your scala client, the CLI or a GUI client like [mqtt-explorer](http://mqtt-explorer.com/) mean while you check what is being logged in `/mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log`? were you able to reach the container? looks like the mosquitto container started ok and from the inside you can publish message and subscribe to the topic to consume the message

Comment: Yes, edited my post again with the log output.

Comment: I think that the whenReady in my test is causing the problem, I removed it and I can see now that the "In here ****************** " is getting printed, but I do not see any message being read by the subscriber. The logs show this: 1696311473: New connection from 192.168.208.1:37720 on port 1883.
1696311473: New connection from 192.168.208.1:37736 on port 1883.
1696311473: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1696311473: Client <unknown> closed its connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255508/discussion-between-joesan-and-gaston-schabas).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like we're attempting to use a version of the MQTT5AsyncClient with the [hivemq-mqtt-client](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client) as mentioned by Gastón Schabas previously.

As Gastón has mentioned above with their working example, this should allow a simple connection to the MQTT broker.  Based on what has been provided, it looks like there may be a component from the builder that is inaccurately configuring the client.

My initial recommendation would be to attempt to utilize the Async example that lives within the HiveMQ repo as an initial test, and then build additional functionality using this example as a known-good template.  This async demo can be found [here](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/hivemq/client/mqtt/examples/AsyncDemo.java).

Best,

Aaron from the HiveMQ Team

Comment: I'm using the very same example that Gastón has provided, but still I could not get it to work. Strangely the topic seems not to be created when I publish. I can see that the client is getting connected, but after that I see a disconnect message and nothing happens. I have never experienced such simple connection problems just dragging for days together!